# What does >> do in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In reviewing "Crossfilter" source I came across a function that used >>.  Below is the function :

```
  // Similar to bisectLeft, but returns an insertion point which comes after (to
  // the right of) any existing entries of x in a.
  //
  // The returned insertion point i partitions the array into two halves so that
  // all v <= x for v in a[lo:i] for the left side and all v > x for v in
  // a[i:hi] for the right side.

  function bisectRight(a, x, lo, hi) {
    while (lo < hi) {
      var mid = lo + hi >> 1;
      if (x < f(a[mid])) hi = mid;
      else lo = mid + 1;
    }
    return lo;
  }
```

Google isn't returning any results and I have never seen this before.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It's like Math.floor(n/2).  In the example above, note that the `+` has higher precedence than bit-shift, so `mid` will be `(lo + hi) >> 1`.

Comment: In case you'll have future doubts, you can try to figure it out running very simple code (like `a=10; alert(a >> 1);`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitwise shift, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 6):

It's the [sign-propagating right shift operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.3E.3E_%28Sign-propagating_right_shift%29):

> This operator shifts the first operand the specified number of bits to
>   the right. Excess bits shifted off to the right are discarded. Copies
>   of the leftmost bit are shifted in from the left. Since the new
>   leftmost bit has the same value as the previous leftmost bit, the sign
>   bit (the leftmost bit) does not change. Hence the name
>   "sign-propagating".

Answer (score 1):

It does right bitwise shift, which is *roughly* similar to integer division by 2^x (and in your example - just division by 2 to find average). It is one of [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) that happen to exist in many languages and work with binary representation of numbers. It is often used for performance reasons as it is almost always faster than division.